# Python RegEx matching file path with lowercase directory at start

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, directory

I am trying to match filepaths where the first folder starts with a lower case letter in Python 3.
Things that should be matched in the beginning of file path:

```
/var/
/etc/
/tmp/
/private/
...
```

Things that should NOT be matched:

```
/User/
/Library/
/System/
/User/etc/
/User/bin/
...
```

I have tried the following RegEx, but it does not work:

```
/^(\/[a-z]\/)
```

Thank you!

Comment: ^ matches start of text or line of text and won't match after the beginning /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might get along with

```
^/[a-z]\S+
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/QVycvr/1/).

---

In `Python`:

```
import re

lst = ["/var/", "/etc/", "/tmp/", "/private/", "/User/", "/Library/", "/System/", "/User/etc/", "/User/bin/"]
rx = re.compile(r'^/[a-z]\S+')
filtered = [path for path in lst if rx.match(path)]
print(filtered)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to handle any characters coming after the first small character. Try this -

```
^/[a-z].*/
```

[Demo](https://pythex.org/?regex=%5E%2F%5Ba-z%5D.*%2F&test_string=%2Fvar%2F%0A%2Fetc%2F%0A%2Ftmp%2F%0A%2Fprivate%2F%0A%2Fvar%2F%0A%2Fetc%2F%0A%2Ftmp%2F%0A%2Fprivate%2F&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)